# updating a date type in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date field in mysql table (dueDate) . I have tried to update that column in this way: 
I have a function that receives 4 parameters: the taskId - to identify the row, and the parameters of the new date: year,month,day.

```
 function editTask($taskId,$year,$month,$day){
      $str= $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
      $date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($str));
      $result = mysql_query("UPDATE tasks SET dueDate='$date' WHERE taskId = $taskId");
 }
```

but it changes the date collumn to be 0-0-0.

why isn't working ?

after adding the quoting it changes the date to be 1969-12-31 instead of 0-0-0. does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: what is datatype for dueDate field ?

Comment: what is the value of variable $date

Comment: You only need to do `$date= sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $day);`

Comment: It is not working because you are not passing a date literal in your query. `2014-09-29` is just a mathematical operation – `'2014-09-29'` would be a date literal.

Comment: First thing you have to do is changing from deprecated `mysql_*` functions to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You need to enclose it with `quotationmarks '' ` for this.

Comment: well now after adding '' it is updating the date to be 1969-12-31...why?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. So you have to enclose the date within quotes. Also you are creating a string from the date values. So there is no need of using `strtotime()`. Try like

```
$str= $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE tasks SET dueDate='$str' WHERE taskId = $taskId");
```

Note:

> MySQL recognizes DATE values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD' format. A “relaxed”
>     syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the
>     delimiter between date parts. For example, '2012-12-31', '2012/12/31',
>     '2012^12^31', and '2012@12@31' are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDD' or 'YYMMDD'
>     format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example,
>     '20070523' and '070523' are interpreted as '2007-05-23', but '071332'
>     is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes
>     '0000-00-00'.
> - As a number in either YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD format, provided that the
>     number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905 and 830905 are
>     interpreted as '1983-09-05'.

Comment: @Shiran..May be you are doing something wrong. I have tested it in my local and is working fine. What are the values of `$year`, `$month` and `$day`?

Comment: ok I ll check  everything again.. so for updating "date" type it's enought to assign it to a string.. no need to create a date type object?

Comment: It works..I forgot to get the values from _POST before sending them..thanx